# Binding to relationship property

Tags: binding, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to bind an attribute of a `DS.belongsTo` relationship like this:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  text: DS.attr('string'),
  user: DS.belongsTo('App.User'),

  userNameBinding: 'user.name'
});
```

I know this example is a little bit stupid, but the idea is here.

Unfortunately, it does not work (in [model.js, at this line](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/model.js#L90)):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'send' of null

I also tried to use `Ember.Binding.oneWay`, but it does not work either. My current workaround is pretty ugly:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  // code omitted

  userName: function() {
    return this.get('user.name');
  }.property('user.name')
});
```

You can test it [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lcoq/smPZN/1/).

*Ember version used:*

- ember-data on [master](https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/4b35be22d84ca13c5e8e0e2cb7447ab21892b8b1)
- ember [v1.0.0-pre.2-311-g668783a](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/668783a620bc004daa063df72c3d84035be6888a)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There appears to be a bug with bindings to properties that rely on state set up in `init`. I have filed a bug [on the Ember issue tracker](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1789).

For a less ugly solution, you can use `Ember.computed.alias`:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  text: DS.attr('string'),
  user: DS.belongsTo('App.User'),

  userName: Ember.computed.alias('user.name')
});
```

I have a working example in [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/edusir/1/edit).

Comment: FYI, this is in master but is not part of pre.2. In the meantime, @louiscoquio's workaround is equivalent.